# Can I prevent a Javascript popup from appearing on certain child records?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, page-layout, popup

We've created a Javascript popup (that appears when certain account fields are populated) -- this was implemented in a similar fashion to what's outlined here: [Can I create a popup/alert window/message when a SF page loads?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/490/can-i-create-a-popup-alert-window-message-when-a-sf-page-loads)

However, this popup currently pops up in all child records too (opportunities, cases, etc.). Is there anyway to avoid this popup from occurring on cases? Our support team is getting a bit peeved...