# Auto populate message when opportunity is closed?

Tags: pagemessages

I need to auto populate a message when the opportunity stage set to closed. Can one tell how to do this and also tell me any links for this. Thanks in advance

Regards,
Lavanya.

Answer (score 2):

I think u can do with work flow field update, check below links

http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/creating_workflow_rules.htm

http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/workflow_field_update_considerations.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to auto populate a message which is similar to alert message. Which means when we the select the opportunity stage to closed won or closed lost, it must display a   alert message like this" your opportunity is closed, would you like do so yes or no".

Comment: i think there are two ways, one is using trigger after insert event , but in this case we can add message to the page, not like alert. If u want to do the alert with in standard page u can do with java script functions, but script should always on sidebar.

Comment: thanks again. Can you just share any link regarding this.

Comment: do you want to try trigger method or JS one, i think below link useful  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/482/how-can-i-execute-javascript-on-a-sfdc-standard-detail-page

Answer (score 0):

One small change in my requirement. I am having one custom object "Site" which has lookup relationship with opportunity. Which means each site record has more than one opportunity. For example if a site record has 5 opportunity in that 4 opportunity has already closed then when i am trying to close the last opportunity in that site record it must display a alert message " your opportunity is closed, would you like to close the site record also yes or no". If i press yes means it must go to that particular site record their we can manually close the site record.

Comment: Pls update the question instead of adding it as an answer. You can click the link edit and update the question