# How can I execute JavaScript on a SFDC Standard Detail Page update

Tags: visualforce

im trying to acomplish what is said in this question: [How can I execute JavaScript on a SFDC Standard Detail Page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/482/how-can-i-execute-javascript-on-a-sfdc-standard-detail-page).

but i salesforce is blocking me from doing it, when i try to save my script on the narrow component, it just delete my `<script>` tag

can anyone confirm if they are blocking this technique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Confirmed, JavaScript is no longer allowed in sidebar components as of the Summer '14 release. You must embed your JS in a Visualforce page or onclick button.

This is discussed in detail on this other Stack Exchange thread:

[End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-hacks)