# How to change the object specific help link text

Tags: apex, help, helptext, object

I have added custom help links to my objects to go via VisualForce pages and then redirect to our companies documentation website. This is all working fine.

I have been asked to try altering the text on the link on the native UI. The link currently reads: "Help for this Page". I would like it to read: "How to create Object X" or something similar.

Is this possible? And if so,  how?

My searching around on the internet seems to suggest that this isn't possible. No one is talking about it and no one seems to have documented a way to do it.

Comment: I presume you are talking about standard page layouts, no VF pages?

Comment: @crop1645 That's correct, yes.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a hack, but you can use JavaScript to accomplish this.

Take a look at this thread on how to doit.

Basically you inject JavaScript via a Sidebar component, search for the element, and update the DOM. Details are in the link.

[How can I execute JavaScript on a SFDC Standard Detail Page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/482/how-can-i-execute-javascript-on-a-sfdc-standard-detail-page)

Comment: I'm thinking that "hacks" might be the only way to make this work at the minute. That makes me want to park the work for now and implement it when it's possible on platform. If we implement it with a "hack" in one place, I bet it'll end up being replicated all over the place, which isn't good for anyone. I'll look into throwing up an idea if one doesn't exist already.

Comment: The way to do this that scales and is supported is to overwrite the object page with a custom VF page. Then you could build the page however you want. You could use <apex:detail> tag to import the page layout, etc. However that is a lot of overhead and custom development for something as simple as you state above.