# how to enlarge the checkbox

Tags: visualforce, inputcheckboxes

I want to know how to enlarge a custom field checkbox.
Its located on task page layout and I want to know where can I find the code to make the change, and what will bethe variable where I will make the change.
Any help would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a pretty hacky way to do it.

Using [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/73536/550) answer, I'd:

1. Add a custom button/link to the task page.
2. Make this button as described in the link - it's a self removed javascript package. The button will disappear after executing it's Javascript.
3. In the Javascript in the button, find the element by the `lkid_XXXXXXXXXXX` id - (if a standard field, it'll have a nice readable id like `reminder_set_checked`.
4. Modify it's css like this:

--

```
element.style['-ms-transform'] = 'scale(2)';
element.style['-moz-transform'] = 'scale(2)';
element.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'scale(2)';
element.style['-o-transform'] = 'scale(2)';
element.style['padding'] = '10px';
```

Profit!!!

**NOTE** - name the button something descriptive like "Javascript Injector For Task Layout" so that people aren't scratching their heads about why the button is bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned task page layout, I am assuming that it is not a visualforce page. In that case you cannot enlarge checkbox using css. To be able to apply any custom style to components, it should be in a visualforce page.