# Apex code on details page load

Tags: apex, visualforce, detail-page

I need to call a static method when the details page for an object loads. Currently, the only way I know I can do this is to create a Visualforce page and add it to the profile.

Is there another way?

Comment: What is it you are trying to *accomplish*?

Comment: I need to call a method in a third party managed package/plugin.

Comment: Yes, you can create a webservice called by a self removing button. Let me know if you want details.

Comment: Sound interesting but I'm not sure if its less "hacky" than embedding the a Visualforcepage.

Comment: It's pretty hacky. But it has the advantage of being invisible, whereas the page is 200px that you can't hide...

Comment: @CaspNZ, how does button evaluate without clicking it?

Comment: @dzh, check out this answer here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/73536/550

Comment: You can also do it using a sidebar visualforce component. Whenever page is loaded, this sidebar component also will be loaded. Then using javascript you can access parent iframe URL. This can be used to determine the type of object and if it matches the type you need, make call to static method

Comment: @CaspNZ, thanks for the ref. I had some fun with it and made a useless button that runs away from cursor: https://github.com/sjurgis/salesforce-prank-button/

Comment: Haha, that's hilarious! Nice work.