# Hide some field in a standard page on insert and show on update

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, page-layout

In my contact standard page layout, I am trying to hide some field during insert and show it only on update. Is it possible ? What is the best way to do it ? The thing on my mind at the moment is using javascript or create a visual force page that will be put in the contact layout but I am not sure if that idea is correct. Please help. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You will end up overriding either the insert page or the Edit page .The insert page override is by overriding the new Button and probably the easiest approach .

You can use fieldsets to keep it dynamic and flexibility to drag and drop the fields by admin if field changes .

The Javascript buttons will not be supported in lightning experience as well so its always good to design for future and avoid them

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that without need to a custom VisualForce page. You can use JQuery to scan the page for this field and remove it. JavaScript will be able to determine if this is insert or update record based on page parameters.

You can load the code in a {!REQUIRESCRIPT} on a custom link or button on the page.

This is similar to this previous [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/482/how-can-i-execute-javascript-on-a-sfdc-standard-detail-page)