# How can I execute JavaScript on a SFDC Standard Detail Page using Homepage component type Html Area?

Tags: home-page-component

I am following this link [How can I execute JavaScript on a SFDC Standard Detail Page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/482/how-can-i-execute-javascript-on-a-sfdc-standard-detail-page)to create homepage component. But it will not work for me. I was simply make alert on load of the detail page but it was not worked.

```
<html>
  <script>
    alert("Hello form Html Area");
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Summer 14 release Salesforce remove the support of JavaScript in sidebar component.

doc: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_home_page_components.htm

> We replaced the rich text editor in HTML Area home page components
>   with a new version that supports more markup but doesn’t allow HTML to
>   be manually entered.
>
> ```
> In Summer ’15 we will start removing unsupported code from HTML Area home page components. As a result, components that contain
> ```
>
> JavaScript, CSS, iframes, or other unsupported markup might stop
>   working properly. To use JavaScript or other advanced HTML elements in
>   your home page component, we recommend that you use a Visualforce Area
>   component instead.

[End of javascript sidebar workarounds](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds)

Comment: Is there any work around to do this.?

Comment: @PiyushKumar I don't think we have any

Comment: @PiyushKumar if this solve your problem or answer your question. Than you can accept this answer.